# React-Router: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route` in route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have no idea what the issue is here and have tried many other solutions but none work. Any help would be appreciated to fix this error. Thank you

`"react-router": "^2.8.1"`

dashboard.js (excerpt)

```
<div className="dash-container">
  {this.props.list}
  {this.props.job}
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

routes.js (excerpt)

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Landing} />
  <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
    <Route path="jobs" component={{ list: ListContainer }} />
    <Route path="jobs/:id" component={{ list: ListContainer, job: JobsDetails }} />
    <Route path="accounts" component={AccountsDetails} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

server.js (excerpt)

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme({ userAgent: 'all' })}>
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
  </Provider>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One component, multiple component**s**:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Landing} />
  <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
    <Route path="jobs" component={ListContainer} />
    <Route path="jobs/:id" components={{ list: ListContainer, job: JobsDetails }} />
    <Route path="accounts" component={AccountsDetails} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: I wish that was the fix. I added the 's', but the same error still complains

Comment: Also changed the jobs route? To `components={{ list: ListContainer }}` or `component={ListContainer}`

Comment: I can't reproduce it further, sorry: http://jsbin.com/vokalud/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Vielen Dank! I just needed to make that change `component={ListContainer}`